# Mongoose - How to update object in array and then sort the updated array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document...

```
{
"_id": {
  "$oid": "5bca528b49079d64dd4cea5d"
},
"song_queue": [
  {
     "song_id": "best",
     "vote": 1
  },
  {
    "song_id": "west",
    "vote": 1
  }
],
"room_id": "FHWAN",
"__v": 0
```

My issue is that I need to first update a vote for one of the songs and then re-arrange the order of the array based on the vote count.

I have a way of doing it with two separate queries...

```
// Give the song an upvote.
await Room.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "song_queue.song_id": song.song_id },
  {$set: { "song_queue.$.vote": song.votes }},
  { new: true }
);

// Sort the queue.
room = await Room.findOneAndUpdate(
  { room_id: data.room_id },
  { $push: { song_queue: { $each: [], $sort: { vote: -1 } } } },
  { new: true }
);
```

Is there a way to merge the two queries into one query, or perhaps make it more concise? I would like one query that updates the song in `song_queue` and then sorts the array after the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to merge this queries because the order of the operations inside `update` parameter is not guaranteed to be preserved so the code like this might fail to run correctly because you can't be sure that updating `song_queue.$.vote` with occur before `song_queue` is sorted:

```
await Room.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "song_queue.song_id": song.song_id },
  {
    $set: { "song_queue.$.vote": song.votes },
    $push: { song_queue: { $each: [], $sort: { vote: -1 } } }
  },
  { new: true }
);
```

What can be done to optimize db querying is using [Ordered Bulk Write](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-example-unordered-bulk-write) operation which will make only one round trip to MongoDB instead of two.